# Mi back recibe el modelo en null

Tags: c#, vue.js

¿Qué sucede?
Estoy desarrollando un sistema web en el cual el front está hecho en Vue JS(vuetify) y como back Visual Studio C#, en el front convierto el archivo en Base 64 y mando otros datos, sin embargo desde el momento en que lo mando el back lo recibe en null, ya lo mandé directamente desde el front y usando postman, sin embargo de las dos maneras hace lo mismo. Cabe mencionar que si subo una imagen no ocurre el problema, solo es con archivos PDF

El catch me devuelve model.id_art = 'model.id_art' inició una excepción de tipo 'system.nullreferenceexception', y que hago Referencia a un objeto no establecido, sin embargo esa parte no es problema porque el objeto es correcto

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    [Route("api/Remisiones/GuardaContratos/{nombreBase}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GuardaContrato([FromBody] RemisionContratoViewModel model, string 
    nombreBase)
    {

        //INSERTAMOS LA REMISIÓN GENERAL
        if (!insertRemisionContrato(model, nombreBase))
        {
            return BadRequest("Error al guardar la remisión");
        }
        return Ok("Remisión registrada con éxito");
    }

    public bool insertRemisionContrato(RemisionContratoViewModel model, string nombreBase)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "datasource=" + datasource + 
     ";port=3306;username=root;password=*****;database=" + nombreBase + ";";
        string Command = "INSERT INTO contratos(id_art, nombre, NContrato, fecha_Inicial, 
    fecha_Final, fecha_creacion, usuario_creador, archivo, tipo_archivo)VALUES(@id_art, 
 @nombre, @NContrato, @fecha_Inicial, @fecha_Final, @fecha_creacion, @usuario_creador, 
       @archivo, @tipo_archivo); ";
        using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                mConnection.Open();
                using (MySqlTransaction trans = mConnection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection, trans))
                    {
                        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        myCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_art", model.id_art);
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", model.nombre);
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NContrato", model.NContrato);
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_Inicial", model.fecha_Inicial);
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_Final", model.fecha_Final);
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_creacion", DateTime.Now);
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario_creador", model.usuario_creador);
                        if (model.archivo != "")
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.archivo.Split(',')[1]);
                            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@archivo", bytes);
                            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_archivo", model.archivo.Split(',')[0]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@archivo", "");
                            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_archivo", "");
                        }
                        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        trans.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                mConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Código del front

```
           guardaContrato(){
            this.editedContrato.id_art = this.Contrato.id_art
            this.editedContrato.archivo = this.listaArchivos[0].archivoBase64
            this.editedContrato.usuario_creador = this.$store.state.usuario.nombre
            console.log(this.editedContrato);
            axios.post('api/Remisiones/GuardaContratos/'+this.$store.state.usuario.empresaBase, this.editedContrato)
            .then(response =>{
              this.editedContrato={};
              this.selectContrato=[];
              return response
            }).catch(err =>{
                    console.log(err.response);
            }).finally(() => {
            console.log(this.editedContrato);

              // this.dialogContratos=false;
            });
        },
```

Comment: creo que en tu js no le estas pasando bien el modelo creo q podrias probar con algo asi axios.post('api/Remisiones/GuardaContratos/'+this.$store.state.usuario.empresaBase, { model:this.editedContrato, nombreBase:'??'}). el nombre base lo dejo en ?? porque entiendo que deberia ir ahi

Comment: Me di cuenta que es cuando cargo archivos pdf, porque cargo una imagen y ahí si me acepta el modelo